# Source code of apps in windows8

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I want to develop a metro style application using c# and xaml.In windows 8 there are many default apps like maps,weather etc.
Is there any way to get the source code for maps or weather app in windows 8?
Please help me.

Comment: There are more than enough samples [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps) to show you how to do just about anything

Comment: Be aware though that some Microsoft apps have special privileges (like bundling several apps into one package) which aren't allowed for other apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the Windows Store apps are installed to

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps
```

where you can look at them. The JavaScript apps are readable without problems, you need to decompile the C# apps to get to their source code. You can use tools like [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) from Telerik (free).For more info see this article by Justin Angel http://justinangel.net/ReverseEngineerWin8Apps

Comment: Just wanted to mention to the unaware that C++ Windows Store Apps will fail to decompile.

Comment: when i goto link you mentioned in program files i get the error you dont have access to the file although i am system administrator. plz help

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommended you to visit Microsoft Windows Store app site. The site gives plenty of function-by-function examples.
Please download C# 30.9M sample files at below link and it would be good reference for you.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-8-Modern-Style-App-Samples

For more real-life example as you imagine,

- The weather app example:
  http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/99bb20/consume-web-service-in-metro-style-app/
- The map app example:
  http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Bing-Maps-SDK-for-Metro-31b378eb

Comment: Is there a weather example which works for all countries not USA only?

Comment: @TamaraCaligari // not a big deal. You just change the logic of communication. For that, many folks use Yahoo! weather API. In example, http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=1132599 will give weather of Seoul. you can check additional info at here: https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/ you need to parse it and provide to your model.